# Monitor files similar to System Internal's/Microsoft's FileMon/Process Monitor

Tags: delphi

I need to generate an event when a file is closed by another app.

Unfortunately, ReadDirectoryChangesW doesn't report the close event. It would be possible for me to poll (with a TTimer) any file that reported by ReadDirectoryChangesW as modified, waiting for it to be closed (using CreateFile to detect this).

However, what I'd prefer is a completely event driven solution.

Is there a way to hook system calls and detect all file closing events?  I simply want to know the path & name of any file that has just been closed.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the directory changes object does not give you the event? This should normally work without any hickups on any local and removable drive (and most often even on any network drive). Ever tried the explorer change notification routines: SHChangeNotifyRegister?

Comment: He want't to detect the file handle being closed, not file being deleted. ReadDirectoryChangesW does not provide that event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no good simple solution to your problem in Delphi alone - the real solution is to write a [filter driver](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx) to monitor file closing events.

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at Mathias Rauens [madCodeHook](http://madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm):

> madCodeHook offers everything you need
>   to hook code (mostly APIs) in all 32
>   and 64 bit Windows operating systems
>   from Windows 95 to Windows 7. You can
>   choose whether you want to hook APIs
>   in your own process, or in a specific
>   target process, or system wide.

Answer (score 3):

If you choose to go the filter driver route, Eldos has the CallbackFilter component:

http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/spec.php

Answer (score 1):

If change notifications wo't work you might use a very crude and lame method: polling. Every second or so, try to open the file with some incompatible share options. The moment this succeesds, you know that the other application has closed it down.

Not the cleanest option by far, but it will work. This is only an option if you need to monitor a limited number of files and their names are known in advance.

Comment: That is mentioned in the question as a possible (lame) solution, so why repeat it?

Comment: I just stated the obvious perhaps, but I think the pro's cons and impossibilities havan't been mentioned. That's why.

Comment: You don't mention any impossibility. It's possible to monitor an unlimited number of files this way, whose names need not be known in advance, and the OP says so in his question. You don't mention the real limitation, namely that this will possibly interfere with other programs (it can cause their reopening of watched files to fail).

Answer (score -1):

Inside **Jedi Code LIbrary (JCL)**, you have a component named 'TJvChangeNotify' where you can get notification *when a change has been detected in a monitored directory* :

- Changed 'Last write'
  => So it seems to be the exact thing you wanted to do !

Other things it can do :

- Changed file size
- Changed file name
  ...

And best of all, it search inside a folder with subdirectories if you want.
Here is a link to (part of) help file for this component:
http://help.delphi-jedi.org/item.php?Id=172982

Hope this will help.

Comment: The question mentions specifically why this isn't what OP is after.

Comment: No need to be so rough. The question finish with "I simply want to know the path & name of any file that has just been closed" so I tried to reply :)