# hook into a file, read new content in real time

Tags: delphi

How would I hook into a file that's currently in use by another program, which constantly writes out to it? Let's say, there's a text file with 10 lines. When I start my app it has to detect and read any content from there on everytime the writing program saves its content. Can this be done without a constant check on the filesize/date?

Answer (score 3):

You could monitor the folder for changes using the ReadDirectoryChangesW API.

Keep track of the last position you read to, and when you receive a change notification for that file, read from there to the end of the file (as it currently stands).

An example of how to use the ReadDirectoryChangesW API is here:

[Why does ReadDirectoryChangesW omit events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863135/why-does-readdirectorychangesw-omit-events)

Answer (score 2):

Kinda similar to this:
[Monitor files similar to System Internal's/Microsoft's FileMon/Process Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528355/monitor-files-similar-to-system-internals-microsofts-filemon-process-monitor)